# Why can't I send packets with scapy? (python 2.7)

Tags: python, send, scapy, packets

I get this error every time I try to send a packet:

```
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
    __gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 234, in __gen_send
    s.send(p)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 237, in send
    ifs = dnet.eth(iff)
  File "dnet.pyx", line 112, in dnet.eth.__init__ (./dnet.c:1764)
OSError: No error
```

What is the problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, you should connect to the internet with a wired cable and not wireless. I had that error too.